# Написать функцию, которая изменяет слова с символами от 6 и более в строке

Tags: javascript

Вот моя функция, но я не понимаю как реверсировать слова с определенным количеством символов, а те что не соответствуют требованию - не трогать.

```
function reverseWords(str) {
  return str.join(" ").map(
          function(a) {return a.split("").reverse().join("")}
         ).join(" ");
}

console.log(reverseWords("Some string refrejarator traktor")); // Some string rotarajerfer traktor
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Жаль, что вы не знаете что такое if и тернарник

```js
function reverseWords(str) {
    return str.split(" ").map(function(a) {
        return a.length >= 6 ? a.split("").reverse().join("") : a
    }).join(" ");
}

console.log(reverseWords("Some string refrejarator traktor")); // Some string rotarajerfer traktor
```

Comment: Ничего плохого в if нет. Если там не портянка из них. От одного if код грязнее не станет